# Contextual alternative to giant heredoc in python/django

Tags: python, css, django

I'm writing an view that creates custom css files for a poll application (the user chooses their colors, and then a css file is saved, ready for use in their poll). It's a big css file (about 1k lines).

I'm trying to avoid stitching together a giant list of strings, with my variables acting as separators. Is there a context processor equivalent accessible through my view where I can just pass the base.css file and a dictionary of variables (kind of like `django.shortcuts.render`), and then retrieve the resulting string and save it as a file through the ORM? (I have a CSS model with a dedicated `FileField` for this)

I'd prefer to be able to generate then store a static file rather than producing a dynamic css file via the context processor for each page hit.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Why can't you use the template system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as @DanielRoseman suggested, it is actually possible to run a css file through the inbuilt django context processor. First, replace the scss `$variables` with something like this in the sass file and recompile:

```
@function myvariable(){
  @return unquote("{{ cssform.myvariable.value }}");
}
```

Then just pass it through the context processor in your view:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    form = CSSForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        t = TemplateResponse(request, 'base.css', {"cssform": form})
        t.render()
        css_string = t.content
        #now do something with your css_string
```